# Git not publishing all files in a c# Project of VS2012

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2012, github

I'm new at using Git, and I have a problem while publishing a VS Project into GitHub.

Well, what I did was, first creating a GitHub account, then I installed Update 3 to VS 2012, and then installed Visual Studio Tools for Git so I can integrate Git with VS.

Then after that, I created a project in VS, it was a solution with 3 class libraries projects and one wpf project, everything in C#. After that I right clicked on my solution and chose commit, and then published it into a repository I created on my GitHub account.
It was supposedly published at GitHub, but when I decided to clone it locally to another computer, and after entering the project, it showed up a message saying that 2 projects of the solution couldn't been loaded.

Then I made another test, but instead of making it in C# I choose VB, I did the same steps, but this time it was published correctly into GitHub.

Why is it giving me problems only with C#?

Comment: If the projects aren't loading, but they show up grayed out in the solution, there's probably an issue with the csproj file, not git.

Comment: What was included in the "included changes" view in Team Explorer?